# Using BrowserRouter v6, the webpage is not displayed no errors found

Tags: reactjs

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter , Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom"
function App() {
return(
<>
<BrowserRouter>
<Navbar/>
<Routes>
    <Title/>
    <About/>
    <SkillsSection/>
    <Mywork/>
    <Route exact path='/contact'>
    <Contact/>
    </Route>   
</Routes>
<Footer/>
</BrowserRouter>
</>
)
}
export default App;
```

After applying the routes the web page is not being displayed in browser and there is no error in code so far

Comment: Try `<Route exact path="contact">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go through this link
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
// import your route components too

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
);
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/content" element={<content />}>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```